# Make a Pattern using nested while loop

Tags: c++

I am new in programming and I struck at this pattern

```
![Using For loop][1]
```

I want to use nested while loop because with for loop I already made this.
I cannot obtain the correct output....Here is my code........

```
int i=1,j=1,n=5,z=1,c=5;
while(i<=n)
{
    j=1;
    while(j<=i)
    {
        cout<<"*";
        j++;
    }
    z=5;
    while(z>i)
    {
        cout<<".";
        z--;
    }
    c=1;
    while(c<=i)
    {
        cout<<"+";
        c++;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a for-loop? Why do you declare the loop variables outside of the loop? What exactly is the output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are the spaces part of the pattern?

Comment: @AbdulMajeed Two things here, 1. You're loop isn't even printing the same characters, 2. Can you give numbers that correspond to the symbol count you want?

Comment: @saadtaame Yes spaces are part of the pattern...

Comment: The pattern doesn't makes sense

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt using for loop i made it...
Exactly out is like this......
*

Comment: show your for loop then.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt
I cannot able to add picture....
I cannot figure it to how to add picture...
*     *
**   **
*** ***
*******

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to print, but if the pattern is to draw a bunch of '-' signs surrounded by '+' signs where each next row adds 2 plus signs then here is some code to do that:

```
int w = 13;
int plus = 0;

while(plus < w)
{   int need = min(w - plus, 2);
    plus += need;
    int t = plus / 2;
    while(t--) printf("+");
    t = w - plus;
    while(t--) printf("-");
    t = plus - plus/2;
    while(t--) printf("+");
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: Yeah...
It is a same thing that I want to print.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below:

```
      #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i,j,k,n=20,flag =0;
    i = 1;
    while (i<n)
    {
        flag = 0;
        k = i;
        while(k--)
        printf("+");
        j = i+1;
        while(j<n-i)
        {
            flag = 1;
            printf("-");
            j++;
        }

        k = i;
        while(k--)
        printf("+");
        printf("\n");
        if(flag == 0)
        break;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is the same output...
But I want to make it only with nested while loop.

Comment: @AbdulMajeed Removed `for` loop and added `while`